# The correct XML Schema datatype?

Tags: xml, types, xsd, schema

I have a question regarding the XML Schema type.

The type has to be:

text, allowing embedded HTML formatting

what should I use to do this? (allowing embedded HTML formatting? I think for text xsd:string for example would be fine but I don't know what to do to allow embedded HTML formatting)

What should I include in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xs:string` datatype is really not suitable for character data interspersed with markup; that is what complex types with `mixed="true"` are for.

If you're writing an XSD schema for a document type and want a particular element to be able to contain arbitrary XHTML elements, the right way to declare it is something like this:

```
<xs:element name="embedded_html">
  <xs:complexType mixed="true">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:any namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
              minOccurs="0" 
              maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

This won't allow the HTML to consist of tag salad; the HTML will need to be well formed (i.e. be encoded as XHTML).  If for whatever reason you believe you need to allow tag salad as the content of `embedded_html`, then your choices are to reconsider what you actually need or to do as some other vocabularies do and escape the HTML encoding.  But even in that case, I think you'll do better to use mixed content than `xs:string`.

Comment: But even after doing this do I have to put CDATA to put tags like <li>?

Comment: Even if I put <p> it returns were saying that: This element is not expected. Expected is ( {http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml}* ).

Comment: If 'p' is unexpected, I suspect it's because you're not specifying the XHTML namespace for it.   The wildcard as specified in the answer requires XHTML content, so you'll need to write <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">...</p>

Answer (score 2):

I think xsd:string would be a good choice.  It will allow you to embed html inside of a CDATA like so.

```
<xsd:element name="embedded_html" type="xsd:string"/>

<embedded_html><![CDATA[<p>This is silly HTML</p>]]></embedded_html>
```

But you don't get any sort of validation at all, any string will do.

Another thing you could do is just use the schemas provided for xhtml http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-schema/#schemas.  But it really depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: other than CDATA is there any other ways to solve this issue? (allowing HTML embedded formatting)?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the schema is to control the logical structure of the document, not the choice of escaping conventions for character data.

You just add `CDATA` section in your document XML, without modify XSD.

Link : http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp